# Gallery view flip using setSelection(position)

Tags: android, animation, gallery, onfling

I have created two "Left" and "Right" buttons to change gallery item, using setSelection(position method). I am facing the issue that when I flip left or right on gallery it shows the item changing animation/effect. But when I change item using setSelection method, no animation is shown. I have tried `setSelect(pos,animate)` method, but no result.

Also tried using:

```
Animation inFromRight =  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.righttoleft);
                    gallery.startAnimation(inFromRight);
                    gallery.setSelection(currPos);
```

This animation is not the same which occurs when flip.

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate the key down event by:

```
gallery.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT, null);
gallery.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT, null);
```

without using any animation.

Just put these two functions in your "Left" and "Right" buttons respectively. :)

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of setSelection from android sources:

```
public void setSelection(int position, boolean animate) {
    // Animate only if requested position is already on screen somewhere
    boolean shouldAnimate = animate && mFirstPosition <= position &&
            position <= mFirstPosition + getChildCount() - 1;
    setSelectionInt(position, shouldAnimate);
}
```

Is item where you are animating visible on screen?
BTW, gallery is buggy and deprecated recently

Comment: Its not working :(, one item is visible at one time on screen.

Comment: How about making custom control based on scrollview? Its the only option since only one item visible on screen